# swift: Change size of UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I use this class to create circular progress:

```
class ProgressBarView: UIView {

    var bgPath: UIBezierPath!
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
    var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    var progress: Float = 0 {
        willSet(newValue)
        {
            progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(newValue)
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }

    func simpleShape()
    {
        createCirclePath()
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2.5
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor.copy(alpha: 0.2)

        progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        progressLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        progressLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 2.5
        progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 122/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0


        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

    private func createCirclePath()
    {

        let x = self.frame.width/2
        let y = self.frame.height/2
        let center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        print(x,y,center)
        bgPath.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: x, startAngle: CGFloat(11), endAngle: CGFloat(17.28), clockwise: true)
        bgPath.close()
    }
}
```

And in my `ViewController` I use this class for my `progressView`. I want to change size of my `progressView` for iPhone SE. I trying create width constraint in storyboard and change size of `progressView` programmatically like:

```
if self.view.frame.height == 568 {

    progressViewWidthConstraint.constant = 100
}
```

But it doesn't work. How to change size for iPhone SE?

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Where are you setting the progressViewWidthConstraint?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri In my storyboard

Comment: And where are you setting it to 100?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Not. 185.

Comment: Where is this line located? if self.view.frame.height == 568 {

    progressViewWidthConstraint.constant = 100
}

Comment: @RakeshaShastri in viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-layout

```
progressViewWidthConstraint.constant = 100
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Doesn't works. For example if I create another view without `ProgressBarView ` class and use in code `otherViewWidthConstraint.constant = 100` everything works fine. Also my `progressView` change size if I edit this `let x = self.frame.width/2` `let y = self.frame.height/2`

Comment: can you show all the constraints of the progressView in IB , in a screenShot

Comment: Update question. You can see `TimerLabel` and `DesignableView`. If I write `progressViewWidthConstraint.constant = 100` my  `progressView` not changes but `TimerLabel` and `DesignableView` change their size like 100.

Comment: `TimerLabel` and `DesignableView` have width like `progressView`. Their width depends on `progressView `.

Comment: this is the reason of conflict if you set a width for one view , then all attached EqualWidths constraints should not contain any width constraints

Comment: Okay. I remove my `TimerLabel` and `DesignableView` from storyboard. I have same problem.

Comment: If my screen = iPhone SE. Maybe I should update x, y in `createCirclePath ` in `ProgressBarView `?